# Cast String Date to new format Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to cast a date format which is string resultset from database to a standard format, but using simpledateformat gives following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
at CopyEJ.CopyEJ.main(CopyEJ.java:113)

RROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:838]
```

With De-bug I found out variable time_stmp has value "2013-04-19 17:29:06" I want to cast to this:

```
yyyyMMddhhmmss
```

Here's code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

        ResultSet rs_dt = cmd1.executeQuery(dt);

        String time_stmp = null;

        while (rs_dt.next())
        {
            time_stmp = rs_dt.getString(1);
        }

        StringBuilder ts = new StringBuilder( df.format( time_stmp ) );
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Simple DateFormat has the wrong datepattern. You have to parse it to date with the pattern of you DB, then parse it back to `String`. 
Try it this way:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    ResultSet rs_dt = cmd1.executeQuery(dt);

    String time_stmp = null;

    while (rs_dt.next())
    {
       time_stmp = rs_dt.getString(1);
    }
    Date d = null;
    try {
       Date d = df.parse(time_stmp);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Prime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

    StringBuilder ts = new StringBuilder( df2.format(d) );
```

By the way:
If you want your output to be in 24h-Format, then you have to use the pattern `yyyyMMddHHmmss`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DateFormat.parse()` here since the argument is of type `String`. `DateFormat.format()` on the other hand is used to format `Date` objects as `String`.

```
StringBuilder ts = new StringBuilder(df.format(df.parse(time_stmp)));
```

Also, it's recommended to save date/time data as a `TimeStamp` in database instead of a `String`.

Comment: this gives me an error "The constructor StringBuilder(Date) is undefined"

Comment: @user2385057 - It shouldn't be _too_ hard to figure it out from there ;-)

Comment: @user2385057 Don't use toString() as that would use `Date`'s default format. Use a `parse()` followed by a `format()` using your custom `DateFormat` instead. Check update.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, format of the date retrieved from DB is `yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss` and you are trying to parse it with the format `yyyyMMddhhmmss`

You can do something like this

```
    String date = "2013-04-19 17:29:06";
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss").parse(date);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
    System.out.println(outputFormat.format(d));
```

Comment: Might want to check the order of your day and month here :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat.parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) to convert a **String to a Date**.

Use [`SimpleDateFormat.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) to convert a **Date to a String**.

All together now:

```
SimpleDateFormat dbFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat stdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
String s = stdFormat.format(dbFormat.parse(input));
```

You can modify the formats to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Like it was mention you need to use

```
SimpleDateFormat.parse()
```

Also if your string is in the form

```
`2013-04-19 17:29:06`
```

You will want to construct your SimpleDateFormat for reading in like this

```
`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` //make sure you use uppercase H for 24 hour times
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use below code to format date as of your choice (Ex: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date calDate = calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("Calendar Date: " + calDate);
        System.out.println("Your Choice Date format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss): "+dateFormat.format(calDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd hhhh:mm:ss");
    String time_stmp ="2013-04-19 17:29:06";
    Date date=df.parse(time_stmp);
    StringBuilder ts = new StringBuilder( df.format( date ) );
    System.out.println(ts);
```